# How to get exclusive access to audio line in Java?

Tags: java, audio

I have a java application which plays a audio file. So before the audio file or sound is played by my java application, I want to mute all other application sounds like Windows media player, VLC player, etc if those are currently playing at that time.

After my java application completes playing the audio file, i would like to un-mute them again.

Are there any ways to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, this has nothing to do with Java, but that the OS doesn't allow it. Applications that behave nicely should pause their playback when they lose audio focus.

Comment: Actually, some OSes and audio APIs DO have exclusive access mode, but I believe you are correct that when it exists java does not support it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in plain old java AFAIK. You need to use JNI or JNA. There are some APIs for audio access that might do the trick, for example you could use portaudio from java (someone recently announced an opensource project which does does that, ask on the portaudio maling list if you can't find it), but this has some problems:

- it will make your code platform dependent.
- it won't always work (for example, if you don't have permissions, or if another piece of software is already using the device, or the device doesn't have an exclusive mode, or any number of other reasons).
- you must reprogram your audio code to use the PA interface instead of javasound.

Comment: Bjorn Roche, thanks for the help. The mencioned problemas are acceptable for my project. I've searched for your references but I cant find anything related. Have you some link that can help?